# Evaluating expression '[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement... error

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to verify walkthrough popup, every time when it's closed I execute this keyword to open it again but if I execute it several times it fails with error. The syntax is correct as I am able to execute it 2-3 times in other TCs. Could anyone help me to understand where is the problem?

```
Open Walkthrough Guide If It is Closed
${ELEMS}=    Get WebElements    ${WELCOME_POPUP}
Run Keyword If    ${ELEMS} == @{EMPTY}    Run Keywords
...    Execute Javascript    localStorage.setItem('peopleAnalyticsTourDismiss', 'false')
...    AND    Reload Page
```

error code

```
Evaluating expression '[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="461c3d8d360e2040589b1f70653b326d", element="3de37e69-02bd-4b76-8ff0-1bd652b952d7")>] == []' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to run a keyword if `${ELEMS}` is an empty list, I recommend writing it like this:

```
Run keyword if  len($elems) == 0  ...
```

The reason is that, in an expression `${ELEMS}` is not the list of elements but rather the string representation of the list of elements. Using `$elems` is a way to use the actual object in the expression.

From the documentation:

> When a variable is used in the expressing using the normal ${variable} syntax, its value is replaced before the expression is evaluated. **This means that the value used in the expression will be the string representation of the variable value**, not the variable value itself.

This syntax is covered in the documentation for the [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html), in the section titled [Evaluating expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions)